# Vintage Type Image Editing

Tags: photoshop, special-effects, vintage

Image before adjustments:-
[image: before]

Image after adjustments:-
[image: after]

How would I achieve this effect in Photoshop?

Comment: Please read http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/677/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-how-do-i-achieve-this-effect-question and improve your question if you want good answers.

Comment: I want to edit  image(First Link) similar to image in 2nd link In photoshop.I tried it many times but not getting the exact output like image in 2nd link

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove blacks using curves tool:

[image]

2. Remove saturation using saturation tool:

[image]

3. Post photographs online in JPG instead of GIF:
   [image]

Comment: Rather than just remove blacks, you can reduce overall contrast and the highlights will also match the example more closely. But it is pretty much reduce contrast and desaturate.

Comment: I see no difference but if you say so, ok.